# Missing pyconfig.h while installing a package

Tags: python, python-3.x, add-on, nas, synology

I'm using [Python3 (v3.4) add-on](https://www.synology.com/en-us/dsm/app_packages/py3k) on my Synology NAS.

When I try to install package (via ssh using `python3 setup.py install`) it returns error:

> invalid Python installation: unable to open /volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/include/python3.4m/pyconfig.h (No such file or directory)

When I search the disk for the *pyconfig.h* file, it finds nothing and the folder *...include/python3.4m* doesn't even exist. The problem occurred some time ago (in version 3.3), but I searched the disk, found the *pyconfig.h* file in different location and copied it into the proper folder. Now, there isn't any file anywhere.

Is there any way how to fix this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for answer.

Since the *ipkd* is disabled on Synology NAS, I would have to use bootstrap in order to install *ipkd* [(to do so, see this)](http://forum.synology.com/wiki/index.php/Overview_on_modifying_the_Synology_Server,_bootstrap,_ipkg_etc). And that was the only think I didn't want to do also because it invalidates software support warranty. But it worked previously, so I emailed the Synology Tech Support and got this response:

> According to our check,
>
> to keep system stable, we had removed *pyconfig.h* in python3, due to a module base requirement, and Diskstation does not provide cross compiler function.

But they also provided me the missing *pyconfig.h* which I copied to the requested folder and since then everything has worked like a magic.

Comment: Hi, can you please share your pyconfig.h, that was sent to you?

Comment: @andreybavt Here is the link: http://goo.gl/HgzT62
Be advised it doesn't have to work on all versions and/or it can cause some trouble. So check, whether you're running the latest version of DSM (5 or 5.1), which works for me ;)

Comment: Thank you. Just in case, what Synology model are you using with this file?

Answer (score 2):

You have to install the python-development package, whatever the distribution uses your NAS. But if you are able to install packages, maybe you can install directly the python3. Lets suppose you have the `ipkg` command available. Try:

```
# ipkg install python34
```

Or

```
# ipkg install python-dev (or python-devel or python-development)
# python3 setup install
```

Comment: Thanks, I suppose it would work, but I just got it the official way ;)